Can you have a pointer to a data member of a subobject's class?
I've got interested in one thing - in c++ we have pointers to data member, for example:
struct A
{
  int a_1 = 1;
};

A a;
int A::* p_a = &A::a_1;
    
a.*p_a = 10;

But if I have something like this:
struct B
{
  int b_1 = 11;
};

struct A
{
  int a_1 = 1;
  
  B b;
};

... where an object of type B is stored in an object of type A - is there way to have a pointer to a data member of a subobject's class, i.e. something like this:
A a;
/*???*/ p_b = &A::B::b_1;

a.*p_b = 10; // after that - a.b.b_1 is equals to 10

Hope I made myself clear:)

B::b_1 is not a member of A so you can't get a member pointer to it as far as know.

@tadman the notation is bog-standard, where have you been since 1998?

I believe it's a 92 and onward notation till today

@tadman Sorry I've tried to figure out what part of The notation you're using here is extremely odd. Do you have a reference book you're working from? implies that it's not a good idea, but failed.

Your combined pointer to member is just two separate independent pointers to members of individual struct (a bit like a 2D array index is just a pair of regular 1D array indices).
auto [pa,pb] = std::tuple(&A::b, &B::b_1);
a.*pa.*pb = 42;

If you prefer a single operator syntax like a->*pab, you need pack the two pointers to members into a single object, and overload operator->* for it. This is a rather trivial exercise.

I keep forgetting of structured binding . Nice one

I had to look up whether one could write a non-member operator->* (you can)

It's still a pointer to member of B class, because b is a member of B:
struct B
{
  int b_1 = 11;
};

struct A
{
  int a_1 = 1;
  
  B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    int B::* p_b = &B::b_1;
    a.b.*p_b = 42;
    std::cout << a.b.b_1 << std::endl; 
}

You actually even can write auto B::* p_b. Pointer to members are relative to the enclosing class and class with name A::B doesn't exist in your code. That's either a class in namespace, a nested class or a base class of A (if A was derived from B).
Note that a pointer to member of base class is compatible to a pointer to member of derived class:
struct A : public B
{
  int a_1 = 1;
  
  B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    int B::* p_b = &A::B::b_1;  // this is explicitly a B::*
    int A::* p_ab = &B::b_1;    // this is compatible
    a.*p_ab = 42;
    std::cout << a.*p_b << std::endl;
}


edit:
I wrote my answer not understanding that OP was looking for a pointer to member, not just a standard pointer. I'll leave it up in case it somehow helps anyone in the future solve their problem, but it's not a proper answer to the original question.
original answer:
you can, you just need to declare your B variable, then you can reference your nested A variable. So for instance, we can save the pointer in its own variable, then reference A using that pointer:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int val = 1;
};

struct B {
    A aWithinB;
};

int main(){
    B myB;

    //pointer to the A held by B
    A *a_ptr = &myB.aWithinB;

    //print val from the nested A using the pointer
    cout << "Val = " << a_ptr->val << endl;
}

Output:
Val = 1


The question asks about obtaining pointer-to-member, not any regular pointer.

I see. My answer is wrong then. I took a look at this stackoverflow page and it gave me a better idea of what's going on. It also might be worth looking at for OP if none of the answers here work for them. Please disregard my answer. I'll add an edit at the top of my answer for anybody else who comes to this page in the future.
